# Save the client HTML content back to the Server as a HTML file

Tags: javascript, html, asp.net, forms

I want to create an HTML form on the Server.  When the client completes the form and clicks submit, I want to be able to save HTML form and data in a single HTML file on the server.

The best suggestion I have seen is using JavaScript.  Use a client side script that on click will save the document.InnerHTML to a var that can then be submitted back to the server.

Is this the best approach, or is there an easier way?

Comment: how would the user fetch the html they sent the server?

Comment: Why save it as an html file?  IMO, saving the data to a database will be better.

Comment: Basically my goal is to use HTML forms as my document engine.  This would be similar to how PDF forms works.  Once a form is complete it is saved with the field contents to a single file.  This means that the context of the users responses would also be saved.

Answer (score 1):

Even though I have no idea why you want to save the whole html code because I'm sure there will be parts that are the same for every user and you will be wasting memory, but ok.

So there are two ways to do this:
1. is javascript as you said
2. would be to put all the generated html code into a hidden form input (already on server side)

the first one seems more comprehensive and this is what I would do but the second one would also work for users with js disabled.

Answer (score 0):

I wouldn't really recommend this way, because I'm still a huge fan of saving data in a database, but here's a general outline of what to do:

1. User fills out the form and submits.
2. Server-side code executes a method:
   a. String holding the template for your HTML page with placeholders for the fields.
   b. Use String.Format to put all the user input into the correct places.
   c. Create a file, write the string to the file, and save.
   d. Return file name to user.

HTML files are not that large, but still you risk using up your hard drive space.  Also, you need write permissions which introduces security risks.

Going the database route:
1. User fills out the form and submits.
2. Server-side code saves the data to a database, and returns a link (with querystring string of ID and possibly a user id to help with security) to the user.
3.  Whenever the user goes to the link, the server-side code repopulates the form with the ID passed.